# Determine monthly payments with interest rate and year

Tags: calculus

Suppose the interest rate on the car loan is r% and equal monthly payments are to be made for t years. Then for each $1200 borrowed the monthly payment M is given by

$$M = \frac{r}{1 - (1 + \frac{r}{1200})^{-12t}}$$

If you buy a Mini-Cooper costing $24, 000 what will your monthly payment be on a 3 year loan when the interest rate on the loan is 6%?

To solve this problem, I first plugged in the $r$ and $t$ values into the equation, which gave me approximately $\$33.36$. However, all of the possible answers for this question are in the $\$700$ range, so I'm uncertain of how to proceed. I'm also uncertain of what the question is asking in the first place - for instance, why is $\$1200$ relevant to begin with? I tried doing $\frac{24000}{33.36}$, and that gave me $\$719.33$, which was not one of the answers either.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is messed up.  First, the whole mess should be multiplied by the PV (present value) which is \$24,000.  Second, there's a confusion in the $r$.  The 1200 is not a dollar amount, but 12 times 100.  The 12 is because the rate is in years, but the payment is in months.  The 100 is to convert the $r=6$ into $6\%$.  Which means that the $r$ in the numerator should be divided by 100 also.  (Either $r=6$ and we talk about $r\%$ or $r=0.06$ and we talk about the rate being $r$ (no percent sign.) This formula is mixing the two ways to do it.)
Also the numerator should be divided by 100 if the $r$ in the denominator is.)

That makes the calculation $0.0304$ times PV = \$730.13.$